# Check whether cl_mem object is valid

Tags: opencl

What I am trying to do seems rather simple to me, but at the moment I have the feeling it is not possible with OpenCL:

I want to check whether some `cl_mem` object is actually valid before releasing it:

```
cl_mem someimage;
if ( isvalid(someimage) ) clReleaseMemObject(someobject);
```

The reason is simple: If I call `clReleaseMemObject` without initializing `someimage`, my program crashes. I could put a `try ... catch` around the call, but this seems somehow dirty to me.

Any call like `clGetImageInfo(someimage)` also crashes, if it is not initialized.

How could I implement `isvalid(someimage)`?

Many thanks for any hints,
Jakob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Khronos forum (see http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=4995 ) I learned that `cl_mem` is a pointer type and can thus be savely initialized to `nullptr` and checked before releasing or querying. A completely uninitialized pointer on the stack gives errors, of course.

Thanks to notzed.